# Arrange the display of foreach loop like a list

Tags: html, laravel

Hope anyone could help me format the display of this `foreach` loop. Its result is in single line. I'd tried some ways but no luck. What I want is to look like in a list.

```
  database table
    id     policies_content
    1      No Grade Below 89 Warning
    2      No policy
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    Scholarship Policy:
        @foreach($ship['shipPolicy'] as $pol)
            {!! $pol['policies_content'] !!}
        @endforeach
</div>
```

result is this -->

```
Scholarship Policy: No Grade Below 89 Warning No policy
```

Desired output:

```
Scholarship Policy: 
    No Grade Below 89 Warning 
    No policy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not forget to use html markup, if you want to display as a list:

```
<ul>
  @foreach($ship['shipPolicy'] as $pol)
      <li> {{ $pol['policies_content'] }} </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

I added unlinked list tags and listitem tags http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_unordered

Comment: Thank you it works and I just added css to hide the bullets.